# $A$ regular, $k'/k$ transcendental. How to prove that $A \otimes_k k'$ is regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $k'$ a purely transcendental extension of $k$.

Let now $A$ be an integral finitely generated $k$-algebra.

> How to prove that if $A$ is regular then $A \otimes_k k'$ is also
>   regular?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use a result of Grothendieck which says:

> If $k'$ and $K$ are extension fields of $k$ such that
>   either $k'$ or $K$ is finitely generated over $k$ and if $k'$ is separable over $k$, then $k'\otimes_kK$ is regular.

and the Theorem 33.2(i) from Matsumura, CRT, which asserts:

> If $A\to B$ is a faithfully flat and regular morphism of Noetherian rings, then $A$ is regular iff $B$ is regular.

Now notice that the morphism $k\to k'$ is regular (use the Grothendieck's result), then change the base via the finite type morphism $k\to A$ and get that $A\to k'\otimes_kA$ is regular. Apply the theorem from Matsumura and you are done.

Comment: Very interesting, just a thing: can you add a reference about separability of purely trascendental extensions?

Comment: @JosephCurwen Hungerford, Algebra, Theorem 2.7, page 321 or google the relevant words (this gave me [this reference](https://books.google.ro/books?id=uIlKA0MBNEMC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=%22purely+transcendental+extension%22+%22separable%22&source=bl&ots=Ehx-94BgE5&sig=BLJXTifEFur1RaGEfigac1-2_VQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TD-RVcCKIIr9UuvHsLAI&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)).